# Emacs run forward char in a hook

Tags: emacs, elisp

I wrote this below to get to search for the next period in tex mode. It works fine except trying to get it to move forward a char after it finds the period. I am not sure how to do this but here was my attempt.

```
(add-hook 'text-mode-hook (lambda ()                                                                                                                                                                                                 
                (local-set-key (kbd "s-p")                                                                                                                                                                                            
                       (lambda () (interactive) ((search-backward "." nil t) (forward-char))))))
```

Final solution I combined the functions from ajk solution. I couldn't get the other one working without the add-hook. Someone might know how to get the second one working. The below completely works and searches backward for the previous period unless it is currently at a period.

```
(add-hook 'text-mode-hook
      (lambda ()
        (local-set-key (kbd "s-p")
                       (lambda ()
                         (interactive)
                          (if (looking-back "\.")
                         (backward-char))
                         (search-backward "." nil t)
                         (forward-char)))))
```

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have parentheses around the last two function calls in the anonymous function you're assigning to the key, causing Emacs Lisp to think you want to call a function named `(search-backward "." nil t)`.  Try

```
(add-hook 'text-mode-hook
          (lambda ()
            (local-set-key (kbd "s-p")
                           (lambda ()
                             (interactive)
                             (search-backward "." nil t)
                             (forward-char)))))
```

The problem I would have with this binding is it's not repeatable.  If you run it a second time, it finds the same period you just found.  You might want to check to see if the previous character is a period and if so, skip it.  Also, you can simplify it a bit by using `define-key` to add the binding explicitly to the `text-mode` keymap:

```
(define-key text-mode-map (kbd "s-p")
  (lambda ()
    (interactive)
    (if (looking-back "\.")
        (backward-char))
    (search-backward "." nil t)
    (forward-char)))
```

Comment: @ajk-The bottom one doesn't work properly. It just goes directly to the start of the line. I think it may have to be with the change to the add-hook. Not really sure.

Comment: @J Spen: Hm, I can't get it to fail that way.  The only thing I'm doing differently than what I posted is I'm using a different key sequence (C-c C-p) because I don't have a Super key.

Comment: not really sure what the deal is then but the other one works fine I posted. I will have a look to see if it is something to do with the super key but I doubt it. I will check. Thanks for the help.